# C - getopt incorrectly interprets next option as argument for previous option

Tags: c, getopt

I'm using `getopt` the following way:

```
     while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, ":a:b")) != -1) {
        switch (c) {
        case 'a':
          printf("option: a argument: %s\n", optarg);
          break; 
        case 'b':
          printf("option: b\n");
          break;
        case ':':
          if(optopt == 'a') {
            printf("option: a argument: default\n");
          else {
            fprintf(stderr, "argument required!\n");
          }
    }
```

The idea is to have option `a` take an optional argument, and use a default if none is provided.

However, if I run my program like this:
`./main -a -b`, what ends up getting printed is:

```
option a: argument -b
```

What I want is:

```
option: a argument: default
option: b
```

How can I get `getopt` to realize what's following `-a` is in fact another option and not its argument?

Answer (score 1):

> getopt incorrectly interprets next option as argument for previous option

No, getopt correctly interprets the next argument as an argument, as it should.

> How can I get getopt to realize what's following -a is in fact another option and not its argument?

You cannot - getopt does not support optional arguments. You may: accept the limitations, roll your own option parsing method or use a different utility for option parsing.

Answer (score 0):

from the MAN page:

```
optstring is a string containing the legitimate option characters.   If
   such  a  character is followed by a colon, the option requires an argument, so getopt() places a pointer to the following text  in  the  same
   argv-element,  or  the  text  of the following argv-element, in optarg.
   Two colons mean an option takes an optional arg;
```

therefore, this: `":a:b"`  would be better written as: `"a::b" which allows '-a' to have an optional argument and 'b' to have no argument.

read the details for [getopt](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html)  and [how to use getopt](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt)

Comment: `Two colons mean an option takes an optional arg; .... This is a GNU extension.`